# Best practice with sessions (gorilla/sessions)

Tags: session, go

Before starting using sessions in golang I need answers to some questions

## session example

```
import "github.com/gorilla/sessions"

var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("33446a9dcf9ea060a0a6532b166da32f304af0de"))

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "session-name")
    
    session.Values["foo"] = "bar"
    session.Values[42] = 43
    session.Save(r, w)
    
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello world :)")
}

func main(){
    store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Domain:     "localhost",
        Path:       "/",
        MaxAge:     60 * 15,
        Secure:     false,
        HttpOnly:   true,
    }
}
```

## Q1:

Is it possible to add multiple sessions on the same domain with different names?

```
session1, _ := store.Get(r, "session-name-1")
session2, _ := store.Get(r, "session-name-2")
```

When do you need multiple sessions on the same domain?

## Q2:

What is the best practice to get the variables from the session?
my_session_var = session.Values["foo"]

## Q3:

How to check if the session is saved correctly? If you access the same `map` to both set and get variables?

## update

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

var (
    store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("33446a9dcf9ea060a0a6532b166da32f304af0de"))
)

type handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, s *sessions.Session)

func (h handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "session-name")
    
    h(w, r, session)
}

func Handler_404(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, s *sessions.Session){
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Oops, something went wrong!")
}
```

error

```
# command-line-arguments
.\mux.go:101: cannot convert Handler_404 (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, *sessions.Session)) to type http.HandlerFunc
```

Answer (score 5):

The article "[BASIC EXTENSION OF GO’S HTTP HANDLERS](http://simonsdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/extending-gos-http-handlers/)" ([Simon Whitehead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517578/simon-whitehead))  shows an example of where and when to define session.
Instead of doing it in the `Handler` itself, and having to duplicate a lot of code when you define other Handlers.

With a [named type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types), you can define the `Handler` you need:

```
type handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *mgo.Database)
```

(in your case, it would be a gorilla sessions instead of a mgo session or database)

The [`init()` function](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) can take care of the session creation (here mgo session, but the idea is the same for other framework sessions)

```
func init() {
    session, err = mgo.Dial("localhost")

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

And you can make sure this function type ('`handler`') does respect the `ServeHTTP()` function, taking care of:

- the session management (clone/close)
- calling your actual handler (which can have more parameters than just `w` and `r`)

  ```
  func (h handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      s := session.Clone()
      defer s.Close()

      h(w, r, s.DB("example"))
  }
  ```

Then you can define your actual `Handler` (again, with more than `w` and `r`):

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *mgo.Database) {
    var users []user

    db.C("users").Find(nil).All(&users)

    for _, user := range users {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s is %d years old", user.Name, user.Age)
    }
}
```

And you can use that handler in your server:

```
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", handler(myHandler))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}
```

The idea is to limit the "plumbing" in `main()` to a minimum, while having an `Handler` with more parameters (including your session).
That allows you to use different `Handlers` with very little plumbing, keeping `main()` only for the declaration of the different path (and not for the initialization of session and handlers)

---

Update 2019: in another related context, see also "[**How to handle sessions**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55463582/6309)".

Comment: have updated my question.. get an error when compiling

Comment: @clarkk that would be best as a separate question.