# How to pass a parameter to my auth middleware to get db access

Tags: go

In my AuthMw middleware, I want to make database calls.

**My database variable is initialized in main, how can I pass this to my middleware AuthMw?**

```
func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", ... )
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Handle("/ws", serveWebsocket(hub))
    r.Use(AuthMw)

    //
    //
    ...

} // main


func AuthMw(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        token := r.URL.Query().Get("token")
        fmt.Printf("AuthMiddleware token is: %v\n", token)

        ctx := ....

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}
```

Comment: Have the `db` variable as global, so it can be accessed outside main.

Might want to look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211954/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-my-handler

Answer (score 9):

You have two straight-forward options that doesn't involve global variables.

## Using a closure

You could re-write `AuthMw` into:

```
func AuthMw(db *DbType) (func (next http.Handler) http.Handler) {
    return func (next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // Your code goes here, now with a pointer to db
        })
    }
}
```

That way, you make a "factory function" that returns a new `http.Handler` decorator, where your `db` variable is accessible throught the closure.

All you need to do after this is to replace `r.Use(AuthMw)` with `r.Use(AuthMw(db))`.

This is maybe a little heavy on nested methods, so I'll instead suggest...

## Using a struct

Turn `AuthMw` into a struct with you decorator attached as a method:

```
type AuthMw struct {
  db *DbType
}

func NewAuthMw(db *DbType) AuthMw {
  return AuthMw{db}
}

func (a *AuthMw) Decorator(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    // Your code, now with a pointer to db, goes here
}
```

Then you just need replace `r.Use(AuthMw)` with `r.Use(authMwVariable.Decorator)`.